# Call MyBatis query as a part of custom DefaultShutdownStrategy in Apache Camel

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, apache-camel, mybatis

Good time of the day!

In our **Spring Boot + Apache Camel** project we are using mybatis component to fetch data and process it. Works like a charm.

We also have our own implementation of `DefaultShutdownStrategy` where we override `protected boolean doShutdown(..)` method in order to define some custom actions during shutdown.

One of those actions would be to clean-up some entries in database, in other word to run a simple `UPDATE` query on one row in database table. I want to use mybatis component but cannot find out how to do this in "raw" Java (in my implementation of `doShutdown(..)` method) as we are using mybatis in route context via `.to("mybatis: ... ")`.

Is it even possible? Or do I need to initialize Mybatis again the [MyBatis with Spring](http://www.mybatis.org/spring/getting-started.html) way (which seems to be an overkill for only one query as I already have this component initalized in Apache Camel)?

Comment: How about [ProducerTemplate](http://camel.apache.org/producertemplate.html)?

Comment: @hk6479, thanks! it worked well for my use case.

Answer (score 0):

Following suggestion given in comments, I got it work using [ProducerTemplate](http://camel.apache.org/producertemplate.html):

```
package com.mypackage;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.ProducerTemplate;
import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy;
import org.apache.camel.spi.RouteStartupOrder;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

/**
 * Custom implementation for gracious shutdown.
 */
@Component
public class MyCustomShutdownStrategy extends DefaultShutdownStrategy {

  private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyCustomShutdownStrategy.class);

  @Autowired
  public MyCustomShutdownStrategy() {}

  @Override
  protected boolean doShutdown(
      CamelContext context,
      List<RouteStartupOrder> routes,
      long timeout,
      TimeUnit timeUnit,
      boolean suspendOnly,
      boolean abortAfterTimeout,
      boolean forceShutdown)
      throws Exception {

    boolean shutdownComplete =
        super.doShutdown(
            context, routes, timeout, timeUnit, suspendOnly, abortAfterTimeout, forceShutdown);

    if (shutdownComplete) {
      clearSomeEntries(context);
    }

    return shutdownComplete;
  }

  private void clearSomeEntries(CamelContext context) {
    LOGGER.info("Do some clean-up...");

    ProducerTemplate template = context.createProducerTemplate();
    template.setDefaultEndpointUri("mybatis:removeDataFromDatabase?statementType=Update");
    template.sendBody("hi");
  }
}
```